# HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.- Fiorano ESB

Tags: esb

I have created a flow with RESTStub and RESTConsumer in Fiorano ESB, and when i trigger request, consumer is throwing an error, stated in the title, and some times it's throwing below error.

Authorization has been denied for this request.

Can anyone help me on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just have to pass the input request in Json format instead of declaring it in the REST Consumer parameters.